# JSON Data Formatting Standards

Tags: json

I am converting a foreign language dictionary from an XML document to JSON.
I will have to look up these words for later use and I thought of two formatting possibilities.

The first:

```
{
    "grammar": {
        "verb": {
            "type": {
                "irregular": {
                    "word": "etre" , ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The second:

```
{
    "grammar": {
        "verb": {
            "type": {
                "irregular": {
                    "et": {
                        "re": {
                            "word": "etre"
                        } , ...
                    } , ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which would be faster to parse?

I thought if I break the word down into two letter chunks I could tell the parser exactly where to look, instead of telling it which field to search through.

I am using Javascript, and I will be taking a word from a user.  In this case the french verb for 'to be'.  Then I find the word in my database, and return any associated information with that word found within its field.  For verbs it would be a conjugation table.  For nouns, declensions... and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The first will be faster to parse, since there will be less elements. I think you should consider optimizing your in-memory data structure rather than complicating the data storage format. Construct your json so it makes the most sense, and is easiest to consume.

Do some profiling and testing of different data structures before over-engineering a solution. You might want to use a database like sqlite to help you search large amounts of data quickly.

It sounds like you might want to use a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) to lookup the words. I don't know if json is the best place to structure your data like a trie.

Comment: This seems counter intuitive to me... which is why I asked the question to begin with.  It would seem to me that searching through 10 terms 50 times would be much quick in aggregate than searching through 250 terms twice.  The bigO of these search algorithms always has n being the number of terms.  Less terms, quicker search?  Many instance searches faster than a single slow search.  Am I misunderstanding something here. ...note, there are much more than 500 terms in this dictionary.

Comment: Your question is about JSON, correct? JSON is a serialization format. If you are talking about data structures, you will want to specify what language you are using and find the correct data structure in that language, for your purposes. The correct structure depends on how your search works(is it autocomplete, or full word only?)

Comment: Full word only.  I am using Javascript.  I will take in a word from the user, and find that word from the database, and return the contents of that field.  Grammatical information.  For verbs, conjugation tables, for nouns, declensions.

Comment: Your question sounds like you want to know which is faster to parse, but your comments are talking about algorithms and search. Parsing JSON involves taking JSON data(either from a file, URL, etc.) and transforming it into the data structures of the language/library you are using(which in your case is Javascript). If you want to know about performance of parsing the JSON file itself, your first structure will likely be faster to _parse_, but after parsing into Javascript data structures, any searching is a different question altogether, and is an algorithms question not a JSON one.